# Access azure virtual machine in resource manager in remote

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I have created virtual machine in azure resource manager portal. But How to transfer a file from local machine to azure virtual machine in resource manager by power shell.Please let me know is there any solutions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't because in an azure VM the storage is also virtualized, actually the VM storage is a VHD or similar file in Azure Storage Service.

So, there are no REST APIS designed to write file in a VM 'disk'. Nevertheless You have many ways to achieve it.

- Install an FTP/SFTP client or similar in your VM, then connect to the service and transfer the files
- Use azure storage as a file/share resource. You'll require more development to accomplish that.